# oil sludge in my 1998 Honda Civic LX radiator

Tags: honda, troubleshooting, civic

My 1998 Honda Civic LX appears to have oil sludge in radiator overflow tank.  Mechanic says I need to replace engine or buy a new car.  What would cause this to happen.  Have been very faithful in car's maintenance over the years and am only owner.

Comment: Oil in the coolant is often indicative of a blown head gasket, but there are many other reasons why it would happen. Oil in the coolant alone doesn't necessarily mean you need to replace/rebuild the engine. What other symptoms do you encounter and what other tests has the mechanic done on the car? (e.g. compression test)

Answer (score 1):

There is an unwanted passage between your oil system and your cooling system.  Probably the most common cause of that is a head gasket with a leak between the two, which could be caused by high compression/detonation (there are several possible causes for that including incorrect ignition timing, low octane gasoline), an engine overheat, uneven head bolt torques and/or a defective head gasket.

It could also be a cracked engine block.  That could be caused by uneven heating/cooling (an overheat could do it), or from inadequate freeze protection resulting in frozen coolant in very cold weather, or other mechanical defect.  If it is a cracked engine block, I think you really are in for an engine replacement.  Even a head gasket replacement is expensive (~$1,000) on overhead cam engines, which Hondas all are.

Before you replace the head gasket or engine or car, this Steel Seal stuff might be worth a try.  Here's [a Scotty Kilmer video](http://youtu.be/3suQy44G_B0) on that.  I've had it help on an older BMW, the only car I tried it on.

If you want to figure out whether it really is a blown head gasket or not, here's a [Scotty Kilmer video](http://youtu.be/QA7KVQq9vKA?t=10s) demonstrating a test kit, but if there's oil sludge in your coolant, you definitely have some problem.

Answer (score -2):

could it be the oil cooler inside the radiator leaking